# Edit the original filename of an exe without access to the source code

Tags: windows, properties, exe

Is there a way to edit the original filename of an executable? I don't have access to the source code, unfortunately, but I can try using a hex editor to edit the exe itself. It's mostly just the name that pops up in task manager that I need to change.

Comment: I _think_ there is a checksum, so if you edit the file with just a hex editor it will corrupt and Windows won't run it.

Comment: @Karl I've been able to edit the file (just putting a space in there, but still) and it still manages to run it. Not sure if that correlates, though

Comment: According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) the checksum field is (usually) ignored.  I'm not sure what you're looking at in Task Manager though, typically it shows you the window title (in Applications view) or the name of the executable file (in Processes view).  I've never seen it show a name extracted from the executable itself.